# Android error APK

Tags: android

Hi have this error: \app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v23\values-v23.xml
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>   Error:(24) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
>   Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.`

Answer (score 4):

Make sure use are compiling with version 23 of the SDK and the support library are also the latest. It seems you are using MaterialDesign components, but you are trying to build you app with an older SDK.